# Persist Nav Bar

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I wasn't able to find a thread about this so:

I was wondering if we could make the header/navigation bar persistent to the top of the screen? Sometimes it's nice to see notifications when you're far down in answer territory.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen-optional